# file_get_contents not working with php file

Tags: php, json, api

**Code:**

```
$btc38="http://api.btc38.com/v1/depth.php?c=ltc&mk_type=btc";
$btc38_r=file_get_contents($btc38);
$btc38_a=json_decode($btc38_r,true);
```

I have used other webiste's API and they worked, the only one that didn't work is the above one.
all the websites that worked don't use a php files like the one above (`depth.php`), so maybe this is the issue.

So my question, is there any other way to parse that link into a multidimensional array?

Edit: `var_dump` is used just for debugging, my intention is to parse the link into an array.

Comment: `var_dump` is meant for direct debugging output to the browser and [will return `void` to `$btc38_r`.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php#refsect1-function.var-dump-returnvalues) Remove the call and just use `$btc38_r = file_get_contents(...`

Comment: @sjagr no it doesn't work, if you read my question, I want to parse that link into an array.

Comment: @alex: it's called debugging. `var_dump($btc38_r)` to see the RAW OUTPUT of that url. You're just ASSUMING it'll never return something other than json. **NEVER** assume a request to an external service will succeed. There's exactly **ONE** way for it to succeed, and a near infinite number of ways for it to fail. Always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: I reproduced your issue. @lolka_bolka has your fix. Having debugging code in your MCVE reduced the quality of your question - and thus the misdirection. Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use the `var_dump()` that prints the output. And set some user agent. Without this, I've get back forbidden:

```
$url = "http://api.btc38.com/v1/depth.php?c=ltc&mk_type=btc";
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Content-type: application/json\r\n" .  // check function.stream-context-create on php.net
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n" // i.e. An iPad 
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$btc38_a = json_decode($file, true);
var_dump($btc38_a);
```